# Regex to match and replace a pattern in a file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file which containes an decrypted password `{ KRZ_CONN_PASSWORD=\{AES256:keyfile:a\}9deIfknH7AA3hg+i95mcWg\=\= }`, I need to replace it with a new decrypted password which is below

```
{ KRZ_CONN_PASSWORD=\{AES256:keyfile:a\}UEum+VN9OGFGR/SwTBahgA\=\= }
```

**Actual file:**

```
INSTANCE=s0100r00 [     SECTION=customdefault [ ]       SECTION=default [ { KRZ_ORACLE_HOME=/appl/oracle/s0100r00/product/11.2.0.4 }  { KRZ_CONN_PASSWORD=\{AES256:keyfile:a\}9deIfknH7AA3hg+i95mcWg\=\= }  { KRZ_CONN_USERID=itm6_ag }  ]
```

**Expected result:**

```
INSTANCE=s0100r00 [     SECTION=customdefault [ ]       SECTION=default [ { KRZ_ORACLE_HOME=/appl/oracle/s0100r00/product/11.2.0.4 }  { KRZ_CONN_PASSWORD=\{AES256:keyfile:a\}UEum+VN9OGFGR/SwTBahgA\=\= }  { KRZ_CONN_USERID=itm6_ag }  ]
```

Comment: when you say "decrypted" don't you mean "encrypted" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's|\({ KRZ_CONN_PASSWORD=\\{AES256:keyfile:a\\}\)[^ ]*|\1UEum+VN9OGFGR/SwTBahgA\\=\\=/g'
```